# How to make automation report with using of manual test cases

Tags: automated-testing, test-report

I have an doubt regarding how to create a automation report like how we do a Manual report with the help of test cases.

E.g. Here is one scenario " Email sign up"

> In manual test case, we will cover all the conditions like Empty value, Boundary value analysis, valid, invalid cases and finally we can make a report based upon all the test case like Total cases teste, total failed cases, total passed cases.
>
> So, like above scenario, could any one let me know how to combine or create the Total cases tested, total failed cases, total passed cases after running the automation testing.

Comment: What tools are you using for automated testing? Most have reporting functionalities built in.

Comment: We cannot answer this unless you specify which test framework you use.  If you are asking hypothetically, @FDM's comment is your answer.  If you are using a test framework now but do not _which_ framework you use, please find out.  Whoever knows which test framework you use probably knows how to determine those aggregate statistics, too.

Comment: FYI,
We use TestNG framework in APPIUM tool @FDM.

Comment: TestNG automatically creates a HTML report, and also in XML format if I'm not mistaken... What is your problem?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, how to connect our test case report with TestNG test report @FDM

Comment: Google for how to generate custom TestNG reports.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Selenium tool for automation Testing, It's easy to generate Test report using **TestNG framework.** Just you have to make TestNG class and use appropriate annotations in TestNG.

> Run it as TestNG 
>   -->> right click on Project-->>Click on Refresh-->> Test output folder will create.

**Check**

- emailable report.html  &
- index.html  files in test output folder.

You will get report in HTML which gives detailed status about how many test Cases passed & failed.

> for Ex you may check this one-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use TestNG report if you're writing your automation scripts in Java.

Here are few screenshot of TestNG reports.

[image]

[image]

Here are few tutorial links for TestNG

1. [Link 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/)
2. [Link 2](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials)
3. [Link 3](http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/uncategorized/testng-tutorial-beginners/)

Answer (score 1):

I am using **ExtentReport** for the test result generation, where i can see how much test case is passed/failed and how many scenario's tested along with the information of the person running the automation script. **Extent Report** is an opensource test report which you can download from **http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/**, It supports both java as well as .net.

Extent Report is very easy to use and it have good looking UI Dashboards.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWmYb.png]

Answer (score 0):

Like those above said, it depends on what tools/frameworks you are using.

As we migrated to microservices/CD, we found that integrating our tests with ELK stack provided the best bang for the buck. This allowed us to have a centralized reporting platform, not only for developers, but for testers as well.

Here is one of the articles we referred back to while setting it up:
https://cdinsight.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/build-impactful-test-automation-dashboards-using-elk-stack/

Take care!